# Using JBoss EL with Websphere

Tags: java, jsf, jboss, websphere, el

I'm doing a project which is going to run on Websphere.

I'm using JSF/Facelets/Richfaces for this project.

I want to use the JBoss EL implementation as it allows calling methods with parameters from EL etc.

... usually this is accomplished by getting the JBoss EL jar and then putting this in the web.xml:

```
 <context-param>
  <param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
  <param-value>org.jboss.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>
 </context-param>
```

However this isn't working ... I don't know if its a problem with Websphere or ...???

I get a stack trace when going to the page saying it can't parse the EL where I have passed a method a parameter:

```
<a4j:commandLink value="Delete" action="#{mcsaAdmin.deleteLanguage(1234)}" />
```

Looking at the stacktrace it appears to still be using the standard sun EL:

```
Caused by: javax.el.ELException: Error Parsing: #{mcsaAdmin.deleteLanguage(1234)}
 at com.sun.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.createNodeInternal(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.createMethodExpression(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl.createMethodExpression(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.facelets.tag.TagAttribute.getMethodExpression(TagAttribute.java:141)
```

Note the 'com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl' instead of 'org.jboss.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl' as specified above ...

Am I doing something obviously wrong? Anyone have any ideas... I'm using standard JSF implementation from majorra project or whatever provided on sun website and richfaces 3.1.4 and facelets 1.1.14.

Comment: did you ever resolve this?I am facing same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the problem is not with Websphere, but with JSF implementation, because "com.sun.faces.expressionFactory" is JSF implementation specific. I had the same problem when I used MyFaces for which the [correct param name](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MYFACES-1902?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel) is "org.apache.myfaces.EXPRESSION_FACTORY".

Answer (score 0):

this could be due to a classpath scoping issue. Where have you copied your jboss el jar?

Answer (score 0):

You are right. Include **jboss-el.jar in classpath** /WEB-INF/lib and define in web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
    <param-value>org.jboss.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>
</context-param>
```

**But** There are some limitation. See [here](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.0.1.GA/reference/en/html/elenhancements.html#d0e22695)

If you want to know a good insith about Expression Language, see [Extending the Java EE Unified Expression Language with a Custom ELResolver](http://java.sun.com/mailers/techtips/enterprise/2006/TechTips%5FAug06.html#1) and [FAQ about Expression Language](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/ExpressionLanguageFAQ)

regards,

Comment: I've put the jar in a shared lib setup on the server. I've tried setting the class loader to parent_first and parent_last :\

Thx for the note about the limitations but I'm pretty familiar with EL just never used it specifically this way in WAS :(

Comment: @Arthur Ronald, any ideas where to download latest version of jboss el ? what i found from google downloading seam 2 and use jboss inside it : https://sourceforge.net/projects/jboss/files/JBoss%20Seam/2.3.1.Final/

Comment: @Mahmoud Saleh AFAIK, I'm pretty sure JBoss EL is included by default in Seam framework.

Comment: yes i know i used it from the jar above, but is this the latest version ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the classloader correct? In websphere you have to set the class loader in multiple settings. 
Set the web-module classloader to Parent last and the  application class loader to parent last.

If both are not on parent last, your own jars might not be used, but instead the ones provided with websphere.